# Replace MousePosition cords on dynamically created button to list Forms

Tags: c#, list, winforms, button

Im creating a program in Win Forms c# that you can dynamically add buttons which store MousePosition.X and .Y when you release mouse Button 1.
The problem is that when I have more than 1 button created and use those buttons to input the MousePositions in 2 lists for x and y the buttons just keep adding new Positions when clicking them and Dont Replace the Cords with the New once they just keep adding new MousePositions to the 2 lists i have for x and y.
After that I have another button which when clicked goes through all the MousePositons and clicks on that spot 1 by 1.
Basically I want a Button that Is independent of the Code from 1 button to another so it changes the Mouse Position independently or to track which button was clicked and Remove and Add the new MousePositions in the List's Spot of the old MousePositions so it doesnt keep adding new cords everytime.

```
private void **addBtn_Down**(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            
            Cursor = Cursors.PanNW;

        }
```

```
private void **addBtn_Up**(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
```

*// adds MP.X and .Y to a list to be used in button5_Click. But I dont know how to replace the Cords for the specific button I press again to replace them and not add new Cords to the list.*

```
{

            int xMouse = MousePosition.X;
            int yMouse = MousePosition.Y;
                xInput.Add(xMouse);
                yInput.Add(yMouse);
            Cursor = DefaultCursor;
            
        }
```

```
private void **button6_Click**(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

*// This is the button that creates new buttons dynamically and subscribes to addBtn_Down and addBtn_Up methods which have the code for what to do.*

```
{
                Button newButton = new Button();
                newButton.Text = "Drag me to Desired Position";
                newButton.Size = new Size(82, 75);
                newButton.Location = new Point(leftX, topY);//They arent in this code
                
                newButton.MouseDown+=addBtn_Down;
                newButton.MouseUp += addBtn_Up;
                Controls.Add(newButton);
        }
```

```
private async void **button5_Click**(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

*//When Clicked Cycles through all the MousePositions and clicks there.*

```
{

            for (int i = 0; i < xInput.Count; i++)
            {
                    ClickAtClass.ClickAt(xInput[i], yInput[i]);
                        await Task.Delay(1000);

            }
```

I tried ChatGPT and youtube for a week but nothing worked the way I wanted it to.

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<Button, Point>` as storage (or simply `Dictionary<Control, Point>`, in case you change your mind and use other types of Controls, so you don't need to change the Dictionary). The `Key` is the Button you press (i.e., when the Dictionary doesn't contain the `Key`, you add a new element; when it does, you update the `Value` with the new coordinates)

Comment: There is a simpler way I figured it out answered my question bellow I just used Lists Insert and RemoveAt() methods with (Button)sender! @Jimi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!
You need to use Lists **Short answer** > INSERT(index of button made in a list,what you want to store: (My MousePostion.X and MousePostion.Y)) and RemoveAt(the (Button)sender that has the clicked button information from the list with buttons).
**Full answer:**
**1)** You need a List for the Button List to store the Buttons and have them as its own Separate object so you can track them later with (Button)sender *(The button that was clicked)* and 2 lists to store MousePosition.X and MousePosition.Y. So List xInput; List yInput;
**2)** Then you need to create a Button object that equals to (Button)sender in the Method of your MouseButtonUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) method that you have.And then in the same method that you created that (Button)sender assign it to a variable and use the List of your buttons and indexOf(with the variable that howds the Clicked button(sender) that you assign).
**3)** Heres how it should look like:

```
private void addBtn_Up(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Button clickedButton = (Button)sender; //what button we clicked
            int listBtnIndex= listButtons.IndexOf(clickedButton);//assign index to the list
            int xMouse = MousePosition.X;//I put the information in a variable
            int yMouse = MousePosition.Y;
            
                xInput.Insert(listBtnIndex, xMouse);//Then put the xMouse cords to the index of the Clicked button in the list
                yInput.Insert(listBtnIndex, yMouse);// And yMouse to the same index of the button in the list of yInput.
        }
```

After that I used a for loop to cycle through all the xInput List and yInput List for the MousePositions cycling the same index's aka xInput[i], yInput[i]// basically 1,1 then 2,2 3,3 and so on as many buttons you created heres the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < xInput.Count; i++)
            {
                
                    *//MethodToClickAtThePositions*(xInput[i], yInput[i]);
                        await Task.Delay(1000);

            }
```

To remove the Cords if you use the same Button again and place the new onces you use RemoveAt(clickedButton):

```
Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;//Create another object sender for when you hold the button down to remove the previous List of xInput and yInput based on the ClickedButton
        int listBtnIndex = listButtons.IndexOf(clickedButton);
            xInput.RemoveAt(listBtnIndex);*//Remove both x and y input at the same index of the clicked button*
            yInput.RemoveAt(listBtnIndex);*//After that add the same logic from the insert method from Above after this code so it first removes the old cords and adds the new onces.*
```

**4)** Thats it! Hope it helped to someone! this is all for WinForms VS 2022